# I need a footer div which should be full width to the screen. how is it possible?

Tags: html, css, footer

```
<div style="text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#666666;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;">
Footer
</div>
```

its ma code, i need to create a full width footer div. help me please

Comment: Do you want the div to always appear at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: fixed;` and use `bottom` instead of `margin-bottom`. That way the footer will always stay 60px at the bottom of the screen.

```
div {
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#666666;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yg5rbrdj/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/p4r5asqr/1/

```
.footer{
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
}
```